# XCode 'Build for Archive' HUGE errors in CGRectMake

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm just building my Cocoa app for distribution on mac app store, but this it the forst time I have used 'build and archive'. Now, for all of my `cgrectmake`, it gives me a build error saying:

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setFrame:'
```

The code always affected is:

```
image.frame = cgrectmake(x, y, width, height);
```

This dosent happen in normal debug. What is going on?

By the way I'm using XCode 4 if that makes a difference

Comment: You are going to need to post the actual code that's causing the error for anyone to be able to help you. You'll also need the context around the line causing the problem so we can see the real types of all your arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you are building for the Mac App Store (like you say), then you are using an NSImageView.  Your problem is that NSImageView takes an NSRect to set the frame, which can be created with `NSMakeRect(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat w, CGFloat h)`

Comment: On 64-bit architectures and when `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` is defined before including the headers, `NSRect` is defined as `CGRect`, so `CGRectMake` and `NSMakeRect` become interchangeable. (And I don't see how you inferred that he's using NSImageView.) The problem is either that he has misspelled `CGRectMake` (e.g., in all-lowercase, as shown in the question) or that he is building for 32-bit without defining that macro.

Comment: Because he says image.frame (makes it an imageview) and he is making it for the mac app store so it isn't UIImageView.  I plugged in the code he had and it gave me the exact same error when archiving.  I'm just saying that my answer is right.

Comment: Ah, I missed the variable name. That makes sense. We're both right in that both our solutions will work, but the problem isn't that he *has* to use NSRect. That is one option; building 32-bit like 64-bit (thus enabling use of CGRect for this on 32-bit) is the other.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I don't really know how you can change to the 64-bit alternative.  Thanks for the comments though.

Comment: My answer explains how to build 32-bit like 64-bit. The affected types' sizes don't change, only the ways they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you spell `CGRectMake` correctly. Objective-C is case-sensitive, so `cgrectmake` is a different and wrong function name.

Also, if you're building for 32-bit (as I assume you would be for a release build), the CG types are not the same as their NS counterparts there. AppKit uses types such as `NSRect`, which is defined as `CGRect` on 64-bit, but not by default on 32-bit. Define `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` in your prefix header, before importing Cocoa.h, to make `NSRect` be defined as `CGRect` even on 32-bit architectures.

Defining that macro has other ramifications, particularly with regard to the definitions of `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger`. Do additional testing before you upload to the App Store.